# Is it possible to import and replace macros in a spreadsheet via another macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I developed and support a spreadsheet that is used across an organization. The contents of the worksheets are very stable, but occasionally, I need to update the macros that manage them. Instead of releasing new copies of the spreadsheet, I would like to develop an automated macro-based process in the spreadsheet that checks if there are new versions of the macros and if there are, import and replace the macros that are in the user file. Is this possible and if so, how could it done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to modify existing code with VBA. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811786/using-code-to-delete-code/48812402#48812402. Also, check https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/delete-thisworkbook-code.htm and https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/delete-module.htm. Anyways,I think it would be better if you develop an XLAM file, Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55375406/9199828

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update VBAs in multiple workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016054/update-vbas-in-multiple-workbooks)

Comment: Thanks, these all look like good places to start.